# How to Implement ws-federation azure ad authentication c# web application

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, ws-federation

I am new to azure and I wanted to implement azure AD WS-Federation authentication for my application which is hosted in azure app service.

Application Details: ASP.NET web application (.NET version 4.7.2)

Can you please help me with the process.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- We can add the Identity provider from the Azure Portal in ***Azure Active Directory***

Navigate to the ***Azure  portal*** =>***Azure Active Directory*** =>  ***External Identities*** => ***New SAML/WS-Fed IdP***

Follow this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/direct-federation) to configure ***Federating Identity Provider***

[image]

- You need to ensure that you have configured ***Active Directory Federation services***  server in on-premises environment for the domain which we need to federate with Azure AD
- Also ensure , for this purpose you need to synchronize your ***on-premise AD*** to ***Azure AD***

Please refer [Federation with a SAML/WS-Fed identity provider (IdP) for B2B - Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/direct-federation#step-3-configure-samlws-fed-idp-federation-in-azure-ad)  for more information

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In code level what are the configurations we need to do for configuring this federation authentication.

Comment: Please refer [WSFederationAuthenticationModule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.services.wsfederationauthenticationmodule?view=netframework-4.8) for more information